# Some question about this proof about Riemannian volume form

Tags: differential-geometry

In [these lecture notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wangzuoq/437W13/Notes/Lec%2036.pdf) lemma 2.3. is given as

$\omega_g = \sqrt{\det g_{ij}} \, dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$ is independent of the choice of coordinate charts.

I am trying to understand the proof. The proof is this:

[image]

Could it be that there is a typo? Concretely, is $J = d\varphi$? If not, what is $J$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $J$ here is definitely meant to be $d\varphi$.

In particular, the equality
$$
   dy^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dy^n = \det(d\varphi) dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n
$$
holds, as you can check just by substituting
$$
  dy^i = \sum_j \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j} dx^j
$$
and noting that the matrix $d\varphi$ has $ij$-th entry $\partial y^i / \partial x^j$.

(I'll also remark that it's important in the proof you've referenced that the chart $y^1, \dots, y^n$ have the same orientation as $x^1, \dots, x^n$, so that $\det(d\varphi)$ is positive.)

Comment: The equality that you mention has $det(d\phi)$. But the volume form has $\sqrt{det(g_{ij})}$. Where does the square root come from?

Answer (score 0):

$J$ usually stands for the Jacobian matrix. So yes, $J = d\phi$ in this case.

Comment: Indeed. And is $J=d\varphi$?

Comment: I think so {}{}